# Understanding Antenna datasheet

Tags: rf, antenna

We were using this antenna [900-2600](http://www.wa5vjb.com/pcb-pdfs/LogPerio900.pdf) at an out of town laboratory for RF measurements. The engineer at the laboratory told me that the antenna had a gain of 3dB, but if I calculate gain from the antenna factors in the datasheet I get about 6dBi.

I guess the plot on page 2 is return loss, but what is shown on page 3?

Comment: Ask the designer Kent Britian

Comment: Looks like it's also a measurement of RL, maybe from another sample or from the same sample in different conditions.

Comment: How did you calculate 6 dBi?

Comment: Just plugger the antenna factors into some online antenna calculator. http://rfcalculator.mobi/gain-from-antenna-factor.html

Answer (score 1):

E-mailed the designer as Tony Stewart suggested. 
Apparently the gain is between 4.5 and 6dBi. 
He also said, that he did not know what page 3 was, but it was probably added to the datasheet by mistage.